# Stacked Booster Candy Crush

Tags: candy-crush-saga

As you beat levels in Candy Crush you stack boosters.  Is there a limit?  For instance, I often replay level 1 (over and over) up to 8 times to stack boosters and then use them on the 400 Level rounds. I can't figure out if there is a limit (like if I play level 1 ten times in a row, am I wasting my time?  Did I stop stacking boosters at the 8th play?)

Answer (score 0):

I found that after you get all the boosters, they start giving an additional booster for like 10 minutes. Continue winning and they'll add another item for 10 minutes and so on.